# php telegram bot send text With @ issue

Tags: php, bots, telegram, vps

I have a problem appeared today I do not know why :|
When there is @ in the text, it does not work

```
Example :
if ($text == 'send') {
bot('sendaudio',[
'chat_id'=>$chat_id,
'audio'=>new CURLFile("data/music.mp3"),
'title'=>"nil", <-----// When used @ not work 
'performer'=>"nil", <-----// When used @ not work 
'caption'=>"@Example", <-----// When used @ not work 
'reply_markup'=>$home,
]);
}
```

i run my bot in vps host

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: The message with the audio file(mp3) does not send When I change text without @ Sends the audio file with the text

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to escape the @ with \\

Comment: Thank you
Also does not work with \\ I tried this in advance

Comment: did you try set up parsemode in your request?
February 13, 2018
Bot API 3.6.



Supported text formatting in media captions. Specify the desired parse_mode (Markdown or HTML) when you provide a caption.

Comment: With that too does not work
I do not think the problem With my code
Because I have not changed or done anything he has been working for months
I Think the problem With vps Or something like that :|

Comment: i realldy doubt it has something to do with your vps
it must been your library to send or the api of telegram...

you could test your code locally to check

Comment: I say this because even title or performer if i put @ in it
 not work

Comment: yes - the api will reject your request if you put @ in it?
maybe you should get the answer of your call and check it

Comment: When I put a any word before @ Example
Works Example : hi @ Example if i only say @ Example my bot not Responds
What caused the problem ? And the problem I only get with sendaudio